# Typescript error on accessing hues in MUI theme

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a specific palette set for my material ui theme, which i define as so:

```
createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#193C7D',
      dark: '#112853',
      light: '#2C4DBC',

      '900': '#112853',
      '600': '#16356F',
      '500': '#193C7D',
      '400': '#2C4DBC',
      '100': '#F0F6FF',
    },
```

I access these values, as well as the system colours, even though there's no guarantee of them being there. They ARE on the object, I can log out the theme, and even though its typed as `dark` `light` `main`, the values ARE there.

So even though our `createTheme` lets us specify an entire range of hues, and MUI stores these, they don't appear accessible through typescript? Then what are those options there for?

The end result, is, i have a full range of hues for all my colors i wish to do this:

```
const c = styled(Component)(({ theme, color = 'primary' }) => ({
  color: theme.palette[color][600]
})
```

However, my type system complains that `800` does not exist on type `PaletteColor`. Should colours on the palette not by `PaletteColor & ColorPartial`, just like the input for the theme creation? In short, why does the config let you set all these hues if they aren't used (to my knowledge)?

Comment: I might be missing something, but did you add `800` to your data? because I don't see it and didn't realize I haven't seen it until I tried 400 in an IDE.

Comment: I did, i did some copy pasting of partial data and its caused confusion. Let me edit it.

Comment: The documentation explicitly explains how to extend the theme palette with Typescript. 

https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/#adding-color-tokens

Answer (score 0):

For your specific use case, you can explicitly type the color parameter in your styled component to address the TypeScript error. Here's how you can do it:

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { Component } from 'your-component-path'; // Replace with your actual component path

const StyledComponent = styled(Component)(({ theme, color = 'primary' }: { theme: Theme; color?: keyof Theme['palette'] }) => ({
color: theme.palette[color][600], // Replace 600 with the shade you want to use
}));

export default StyledComponent;
```

Comment: I've tried this route and it doesn't quite work for us. I mean, it compiles. We used `Extract` to only pick the keys of `PaletteColor` that would give us colors, and not things like `action`. But even then that gives us `Palette` | `Color`. Two very different interfaces. Now this is 'correct', but my question more lies, we rely on the values we set for the hue range in our `createTheme` - but we can't access them without hacking the type system to say 'dude trust me, `500` exists on `PaletteColor`

Answer (score 0):

I've 'fixed' this by doing the following module augmentation:

```
declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface
  interface PaletteColor extends ColorPartial {}
```

This puts our 0->900 hues on the object, representing the state of my theme truly. Though I am unsatisfied with this as I'm still not sure why material aren't doing this for us. I feel like I'm committing a code smell.